# Filtering Observable of Array (Observable<Event[]>)

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

Here is my scenario:

1. I have 1000s of Events (Firebase objects) happening at various locations.
2. I need to show list of Events to users, based on their location preferences.
3. Some users might be interested in events from all 15 locations and some users might be interseted in events from only one location (out of 15 different locations)
4. Also, I need to show only upcoming events and not past events (determined by the timestamp property `endDateLong`)
5. So I apply location filter logic locally and time filter logic by using angualarFire `orderByChild`
6. At any time, it is sufficient to show only 30 immediate events to the user, even if they subcribed to all locationss and they should get all 1000 events.

My Solution (design):

1. I dont want to fetch all 1000s of events and filter them
2. Rather I just want to fetch a small block (say 50) filter it with user's location preference.
3. If I get 30+ events after applying the filter well and good. We can display the same in UI.
4. But in case, if the filter reduces the 50 to just 10 events, I recursively call my function again to get next set (based on endDateLong) of 50 events.
5. I repeat Point 4, till either I get 30+ events or till the whole array in Firebase gets exhausted.

My working code:

1. This recursive functions is working well and good and serves the purpose.

   ```
   fetchFilteredEvents(startKey:number) {

   let self                =   this;
   let cacheKey            =   this.fireRoute.getPathForMetaEvents();
   let evListObs:FirebaseListObservable<Event[]>;

   evListObs               =   self.db.list(cacheKey, {
       query               :   {   
           orderByChild    :   'endDateLong',
           startAt         :   startKey,
           limitToFirst    :   50  
       }   
   }); 

   return evListObs.first().map(evList => {
       let cList           =   evList.filter(ev => {

           /** 
            * BEGIN: Check if event falls in any Preferred locations
            */
           let allBlocks   =   self.volService.me.locationPreferences.blocks;
           let prefBlockIDs=   Object.keys(allBlocks)
                                   .filter(b => { return allBlocks[b] }); 
           let matchingObj =   prefBlockIDs.find( bid => { return bid == ev.block.id } );

           // return true, if any matching block is found
           if (matchingObj)    return true;
           /** 
            * END: Check if event falls in any Preferred locations
            */

           return false;
       }); 

       self.eventCount     +=  cList.length;

       // If required 30 items are retrieved or event list is exhausted just return current list.
       // If not, recursively call the function again with timestampe of the last event and append it's return value to current array and return the whole appended list
       if (evList.length == 1 || self.eventCount > 30) {
           return cList;
       } else {
           let lastEvent   =   evList[evList.length -1];

           console.log("Fetch next page @ ", lastEvent.endDate);
           console.log("Current list is ", cList);
           return self.fetchFilteredEvents(lastEvent.endDateLong).then(allEvents => {
               return allEvents.concat(cList);
           }); 
       }   

   }).toPromise();

   }
   ```

Problem with this code:

1. Let's say user prefers events from only one location.
2. It means lots of fetched events are going to be filtered out and several recursions are gonna happen till I get 30 events.
3. It takes several seconds and the UI is not updated till 30 events are fetched or the list is exhausted.
4. The whole function blocks the UI update.

What I want:
I would like to improve the code somehow with just observables:

1. So I can return my partial event array and populate the UI
2. More than Point 1, I am eager to learn Observables good enough to handle this kind of scenarios :-)

PS: It's Angular 2 (or 4) code and AngularFire2

Any pointers?

Update 1 - Conversion to Observables (Nothing much)

```
private fetchFilteredEvents(startKey:number) : Observable<Event[]> {

    let that                =   this;
    let cacheKey            =   this.fireRoute.getPathForMetaEvents();

    let evObs               =   that.db.list(cacheKey, {
        query               :   {   
            orderByChild    :   'endDateLong',
            startAt         :   startKey,
            limitToFirst    :   10  
        }
    }).map(evList => {
        let cList           =   evList.filter(ev => {
            // Filter logic goes here
        });

        that.eventCount     +=  cList.length;

        // If required 30 items are retrieved or event list is exhausted just return current list.
        // If not, recursively call the function again with timestampe of the last event and append it's return value to current array and return the whole appended list
        if (evList.length == 1 || that.eventCount > 30) {
            return cList;
        } else {
            let lastEvent   =   evList[evList.length -1];

            console.log("Fetch next page @ ", lastEvent.endDate);
            console.log("Current list is ", cList);

            // THIS IS NOT WORKING. I am only getting the first 10 events. I think I should somehow merge the returning obserable of recursive calls to `that.fetchFilteredEvents()` to `evObs`, rather than array merging as done here.
            return that.fetchFilteredEvents(lastEvent.endDateLong).subscribe(nextList => {
                console.log(nextList);
                cList   =   cList.concat(nextList);
                return cList;
            });
        }

    });

    this.currentList = evObs;
    return this.currentList;
```

Comment: You could store a list of events per location and then you only query lists that are prefered.

Comment: Yes. I could do that. But that wouldn't satisfy the requirement of limiting only to 30 immediate events.

Comment: I think you can filter that `evList.filter(ev => {...`. Which attribute to filter the 30 immediate events?

Comment: Did that. Will update the partial solution, without recursion now